# CSS dropdown menu takes entire page width?

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I have a simple nav menu at the top of a page I'm working on. I want one of the links on the nav menu to have a dropdown menu pop up underneath it when you hover over it.

I have the drop down menu appearing just fine. The only problem is that the drop down menu items are the width of the entire page instead of the width of a nav menu item. I'm not sure what's causing it...

Here is the html and css for the nav menu and drop down menu:

```css
.dropdown {
  float: left;
  background-color: #FFF0F5; 
}

.dropDiv {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}

.dropdownContent {
  display: none;
  background-color: #FFF0F5;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 300px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.dropdownContent a {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 300px;
}

.dropdownContent a:hover {
  background-color: #fff8dc;
}

.dropDiv:hover .dropdownContent {
  display: block;
  z-index: 1;
  height: 200px;
  width: 300px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.dropDiv:hover .dropdown {
  background-color: #fff8dc;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
      <li><a href="eiffel.shtml">Eiffel Tower</a></li>
      <li><a href="fashion.shtml">Fashion</a></li>
      <li><a href="food.shtml">Food</a></li>
      <li><a href="museums.shtml">Museums</a></li>
      <div class="dropDiv">
        <li class="dropdown"><a href="history.shtml">History</a></li>
        <div class="dropdownContent">
            <a href=leaders.shtml>Leaders of Paris</a>
            <a href=future.shtml>Future of Paris</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <li><a href="language.shtml">Language</a></li>
      <li><a href="works.shtml">Works Cited</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

As you can see It's a bit of a mess since I've been adding lots of things trying to think of something to fix this width issue. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you using any frameworks like bootstrap?

Comment: @Znaneswar Nope, Just the html and css I've created.

Answer (score 0):

Your code worked fine for me. Looks like some other CSS in your code is making it full width. Have you tried fixing it with "!important" or "max-width"?

Comment: Oddly enough adding max-width for this makes the history nav element disappear entirely...

Answer (score 0):

You should create `dropDiv` in the `li` tag and make it absolute position to get the parent widht

```css
nav ul {
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}
nav ul li {
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 5px;
}
nav ul li a{
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.dropdown {
  float: left;
  background-color: #FFF0F5; 
}


nav ul li:hover .dropDiv {
  display: block;
  z-index: 1;
  height: 200px;
  width: 300px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.dropDiv:hover .dropdown {
  background-color: #fff8dc;
}
.dropDiv {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  display: none;
  background-color: #FFF0F5;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 300px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.dropDiv a {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none; 
}

.dropDiv a:hover {
  background-color: #fff8dc;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
      <li><a href="eiffel.shtml">Eiffel Tower</a></li>
      <li><a href="fashion.shtml">Fashion</a></li>
      <li><a href="food.shtml">Food</a></li>
      <li><a href="museums.shtml">Museums</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown"><a href="history.shtml">History</a>
        <div class="dropDiv">        
          <a href=leaders.shtml>Leaders of Paris</a>
          <a href=future.shtml>Future of Paris</a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li><a href="language.shtml">Language</a></li>
      <li><a href="works.shtml">Works Cited</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: This didn't work for me... Now the drop down menu simply doesn't appear when I hover over the nav menu item for it

Answer (score 0):

Hello just define width for nav bar as you want I've defined 700px. and add some css . check this code

```css
.dropdown {
    float: left;
    background-color: #FFF0F5; 
}

.dropDiv {
        position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 9px;
    float: left;
    max-width: 100%;
 }

.dropdownContent {
    display: none;
    background-color: #FFF0F5;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 300px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

.dropdownContent a {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    
}

.dropdownContent a:hover {background-color: #fff8dc;}

.dropDiv:hover .dropdownContent {
    display: block;
    z-index: 1;
    overflow-x: hidden;    
    top: 30px;
    left: 10px;
    position: absolute;
}

.dropDiv:hover .dropdown {
    background-color: #fff8dc;
}
nav {width:700px;float: left;}
nav > ul > li {    float: left;
    padding: 9px;list-style: none}
 ul{float:left;}
```

```html
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="eiffel.shtml">Eiffel Tower</a></li>
        <li><a href="fashion.shtml">Fashion</a></li>
        <li><a href="food.shtml">Food</a></li>
        <li><a href="museums.shtml">Museums</a></li>
        <div class="dropDiv">
            <li class="dropdown"><a href="history.shtml">History</a></li>
                <div class="dropdownContent">
                    <a href=leaders.shtml>Leaders of Paris</a>
                    <a href=future.shtml>Future of Paris</a>
                </div>
        </div>
  </li>
        <li><a href="language.shtml">Language</a></li>
        <li><a href="works.shtml">Works Cited</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

I think this is what you want.

Comment: This is a project so we aren't allowed to use bootstrap as it has to be our own code. Running your code without the bootstrap bits just turns the history tab into a square that doesn't touch the rest of the nav-bar. The drop down options look to be the right length but only one appears and it appears on top of the history tab, cutting off it's bottom...

Comment: This will work even you don't add  bootstrap to your project.

Comment: I;'ve updated code without bootstrap now try and revert back if any issue.